# Why is this flagging rejected?

Tags: discussion

The question is this: [Why was having concubines not a sin like adultery?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/why-was-having-concubines-not-a-sin-like-adultery)

I think the question should be tailored to a denominational perspective, because someone may answer from a fundamentalist Mormon perspective, describing and defending the concept of plural marriage and how it differs from concubinage and adultery. I think the assumption of the question holds that marriage means ***two individuals***, but concubinage does not have two indivduals. Neither do plural marriages. And concubinage and plural marriages really resemble each other in practice. One man is taking on multiple wives or mates. Therefore, I think my flagging behavior is justified.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I can't see exactly what you flagged it for

Comment: The first flag was declined with a custom reason, did you read the reasoning?

Comment: @waxeagle Yes, I did. But whoever flagged it didn't realize my point for flagging it.